# How can i use Dhtmlx Messages in chat application

Tags: dhtmlx

In your dhtmlx message sample examples you said that we can use 
    dhtmlx messages to communicate with application users.

```
That was a great idea.
But how can i do that?
Any hints?


Thanks,
Naresh Adla
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably misunderstood the whole point of dhtmlxmessage, the purpose of that "module" is to communicate your users about actions they perform on your web application, like sending error messages when they do something wrong,or success message, or being able to confirm certain actions like for example deleting or modifying certain information,.

If you wish a javascript chat application you could check here [Jquery CHAT API](http://magma.cs.uiuc.edu/wenpu1/chatbox.html)

or there are plenty of other javascript chat applications, but certainly dhtmlxmessage won't work as a chat.